# Converting PIL/Pillow image to data URL

Tags: python-3.x, image

Is it possible to, in Python3, convert a PIL/Pillow `Image` object into a `data:image/png` URL such that, when pasted into a browser address bar, the image appears?

My attempts so far have failed:

```
"data:image/png,{}".format(image_obj.tobytes())
```

Alternatively, is there any other good way to send images to a remote user from a Python script? Image hosting sites would be good but often are expensive / have no Python API / require signing up and logging in. At the moment I intend to use a service like Pastebin to store the image in its text form and simply send the URL to the user.

Comment: How are you opening the image with PIL/Pillow? For the hosting, if it's not that big, you can use a free hosting solution as Infinityfree to implement the method. When it comes big, you can use a paid service.

Comment: You could try encoding it as base 64... Try encoding the bytes using the base64 library...

Comment: @leonardofmed The image is simply a `pyautogui` screenshot. And I found img10-1342.appspot.com now which only makes one request for uploading photos so I'm thinking of just writing a client for that.

Comment: @EdWard I've tried that but for some reason it didn't work. On top of this, when saved, the image took a few kilobytes but when sent as a URL, a few megabytes which was really weird and a pain to copy/paste.

Comment: The function called image_array_to_data_uri in https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/packages/python/plotly/_plotly_utils/data_utils.py converts a numpy array to data uri

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you are using the wrong prefix. You should do:

```
img_data_url = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64_image_string
```

#### Some useful stuff:

```
import base64
import io
from PIL import Image


def pillow_image_to_base64_string(img):
    buffered = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(buffered, format="JPEG")
    return base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")


def base64_string_to_pillow_image(base64_str):
    return Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.decodebytes(bytes(base64_str, "utf-8"))))


# Example for Converting pillow image to base64 data URL to view in browser
my_img = Image.open('my-image.jpeg')
data_url = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + pillow_image_to_base64_string(my_img)
# You can put this data URL in the address bar of your browser to view the image
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I completely forgot about this question by now and don't have the code to test your solution, but I'll mark your answer as accepted since it looks about right.

Comment: You're welcome! I have tested the code as well!

Answer (score 0):

```
def convertImageToDataUri(imagePath):
    encoded = base64.b64encode(open(imagePath, "rb").read())
    return 'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded)

data_uri = convertImageToDataUri('img/picture.png')
```

if you want to convert datauri to pillow image

```
def convertDataUriToImage(data_uri):
    from urllib import request
    with request.urlopen(data_uri) as response:
        data = response.read()
        img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(data))
        return img
uri = 'data:image/png ......'
load = convertDataUriToImage(uri)
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)

...
```